# Sed: remove all lines with pattern, except those starting with patter2

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I need some help from a sed guru here. 
I need to modify the content of `/etc/hosts` so that all lines containing `foo.bar` are deleted, except those starting with `127.0.0.1`.

I have tried with `sed -i '' "/127.0.0.1/p;/foo.bar/d"` but this doubles the amount of `127.0.0.1       localhost` lines with every run.

Given file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 console-dev.foo.bar

192.168.64.22 apiserver.foo.bar console.foo.bar
```

Expected file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 console-dev.foo.bar
```

Current output:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 console-dev.foo.bar
```

Any sed guru willing to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a line doesn't start with `127.0.0.1`, but contains `foo.bar`, **d**elete it.

```
sed '/^127\.0\.0\.1/!{/foo\.bar/d}' /etc/hosts
```

---

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) you wouldn't need to escape regex-active characters, which is way better IMO.

```
awk '$1=="127.0.0.1"||!index($0,"foo.bar")' /etc/hosts
```

Comment: with -E flag, no need to escape regex-active chars: sed -E '/^127.0.0.1/!{/foo.bar/d}' /etc/hosts

Comment: @alphaGeek nah, it'd match 127000001 and foozbar too

Comment: and -E is a GNU extension, i.e not portable

Answer (score 0):

If a line is doubled, you can get the unique ones, using this simple trick:

```
 ... | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Better still `sort -u`.